# How to make a enumerate list with no indent and no left margin like this?

Tags: enumerate

I thank so much if anybody makes a enumerate list like this:

**Problem 1.** Text text text text .................... text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

**Problem 2.** Text text text text .................... text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text .

**Problem 3.**

a) Text text text text .................... text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

b) Text text text text .................... text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text .

Here are the codes:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\noindent I want to make a enumerate list like this:\\
\textbf{Problem 1.} \blindtext. \\
\textbf{Problem 2.}  \blindtext. \\
\textbf{Problem 3.} \\
a) \blindtext.\\
b) \blindtext.\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: See the enumitem package and its wide option

Comment: To Daleif: I don't understand because I didn't see examples in that package document.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include an answer. If you want to answer your own question, you may. This only makes sense if your answer is different from those already provided by others, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way with `enumitem`: I define a `\problems` (level 1+2) list environment  and a `questions` environment, which is to be used semantically as `problems, level 2`(but technically, nothing prevents you to use it at the first level). Similarly, I defined two clones of `\item`, `\pb` and `\qu`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{problems}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[problems, 1]{label=Problem~\arabic*. , font=\bfseries,  wide=0pt}%
\setlist[problems, 2]{label=\emph{alph*}),  wide=0pt, before=\leavevmode, topsep=0pt}%
\newenvironment{questions}{\problems}{\endproblems}
\let\pb\item
\let\qu\item

\begin{document}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
\begin{problems}
  \pb \blindtext
  \pb \blindtext
  \item
  \begin{questions}
    \qu \blindtext
    \qu \blindtext
  \end{questions}
\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice :) does cross referencing work out of the box?

Comment: It seems it works fine for the first level only. I'll try to see what happens for ‘questions’.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned before, you can use the `enumitem` package.

Using the `enumitem` package, you may specify options to the \begin{enumerate} macro. In the newer versions, you may specify a `wide` option. In the old versions you must specify multiple options to reduce the margins. You may specify the label using the `label` option. The following is an example based on your question:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}    
\begin{document}    

\begin{enumerate}[
    label={\bf Problem \arabic*.}
    align=left, leftmargin=0pt, 
          labelindent=0pt,listparindent=0pt, labelwidth=8em, itemindent=!]

    \item \blindtext. 
    \item \blindtext. 

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The third item in your question may introduce other two problems: (1) How to create an empy item and (2) how to introduce an inner list without additional space.

Fisrt, if you need an item with a blank line, trying to include only `\\` will result an error. According to LaTeX, there is no line to end. You can use `~\\` to include a blank space and then a new line.

Second, when you introduce an inner list, LaTeX may introduce additional space between the items. You can use `\vspace{}` with a negative value to reduce the space. `\vspace{-\topsep}` reduces the space by the length of the top separation. `\vspace{-2\topsep}` reduces the double.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent I want to make a enumerate list like this:\\

\begin{enumerate}[
    label={\bf Problem \arabic*.},
    align=left, leftmargin=0pt, labelindent=0pt,listparindent=0pt, labelwidth=6em, itemindent=!]

    \item \blindtext 
    \item \blindtext 

    % a blank item
    \item ~\\

    % an inner list        
    \vspace{-2\topsep}
    \begin{enumerate}[
        label=\alph*),
        align=left, leftmargin=0pt, labelindent=0pt,listparindent=0pt, labelwidth=0pt, itemindent=!]

        \item \blindtext
        \item \blindtext            
    \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Manually specifying the problem number should probably be avoided :)

Comment: @cmhughes Yes. You are right. I did the change in the answer to configure the label.

Comment: @Jaime. Thank you. But how about "Problem 3." ? After this label name, there is a blank until line ends. At the beginning of the next line I need a level 2 as shown in my text.

Comment: @Exdata, I included an additional example for the "Problem 3".

Comment: @Jaime Thank you very much for your help. Your answer is good. Can you tell me how you resolve this problem ? Examine this `enumerate` package ? For me this documentation is hard to understand.

Comment: `\bf` etc. should not be used in LaTeX. They are 20+ years obsolete. `\\ ` should not be used to break a line except in a special context such as a `tabular` or `array`.